# Problem with template specialization and template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a class `Helper`:

```
template <typename T, template <typename> E>
class Helper {
    ...
};
```

I have another class template, `Exposure`, which is to inherit from `Helper` while passing itself as the template template parameter `E`.  I also need to specialize `Exposure`.  Thus I want to write something like the following:

```
template <>
class Exposure<int> : public Helper<int, Exposure> {
    Exposure() : Helper<int, Exposure>() {
        ...
    };
    ...
};
```

Unfortunately this won't compile.  gcc complains:

> Exposure.h:170: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for `‘template > class ExposureHelper’
>
> Exposure.h:170: error:   expected a constant of type ‘’, got ‘Exposure’

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a workaround for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

if you really want to pass *template* rather then class

```
template <typename T, template<typename> class E>
class Helper {
};

template <typename T>
class Exposure;

template <>
class Exposure<int> : public Helper<int, Exposure > {
};
```

or if your intent is different

```
template <typename T, typename E>
class Helper {
};

template <typename T>
class Exposure;

template <>
class Exposure<int> : public Helper<int, Exposure<int> > {
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first template for Helper, you don't need to say the second parameter is a template:

```
template <typename T, typename E>
class Helper {
    ...
};
```

And you can declare one with a template as an argument:

```
Helper<vector<int>, vector<char> > h;
```

But in your second template, you have a circular definition. Your Exposure class depends on your Exposure class. This creates a circular reference, and the Helper class needs the definition of Exposure before you can inherit from Exposure. You may need to restructure your classes.